# rosserial and arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and ROS Noetic. Following the instructions in the ROS tutorials, using ROS Noetic, everything worked fine except for the tutorial about installing Arduino IDE Setup:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup
I do the 2.1.1 (RECOMMENDED) Installing Binaries on the ROS workstation:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rosserial-arduino
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-rosserial-arduino
```

I suspect that the rosserial Arduino package is not yet provided for noetic. Am I right? Does anyone know when/if it will be? Or can I install this package in another way? I tried the build from source option too, but no success there... it simply does not work when I try to run the simple helloworld example in the next tutorial.
Before I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, I ran 18.04 and melodic. It worked fine!
Any help/advice much appreciated!
All the best,
Krister

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353827/rosserial-and-arduino/) by [Saul](https://answers.ros.org/users/55435/saul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I suspect that the rosserial Arduino package is not yet provided for noetic.

You're correct. The [index.ros.org page for rosserial_arduino](https://index.ros.org/p/rosserial_arduino/github-ros-drivers-rosserial/#noetic) says it is `UNRELEASED`.

> Does anyone know when/if it will be?

When something will be released is a question only the maintainers would know. Good news is it looks like someone asked about a Noetic release here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/499

> Or can I install this package in another way? I tried the build from source option too, but no success there... it simply does not work when I try to run the simple helloworld example in the next tutorial

Trying from source was the right thing to do. Since you discovered it doesn't work, the next step would be to open a pull request that fixes the issue, or if there is already a PR then I'm sure the maintainers would find it helpful if you tested it and commented if it works.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HB](https://answers.ros.org/users/74267/hb/) on 2021-05-09**:
I think https://index.ros.org/p/rosserial_arduino/github-ros-drivers-rosserial/#noetic-overview says that it is released but still I am getting the same error. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was having the same problem. I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and and the rosserial-arduino was not yet available for noetic. I was able to install using the 2.1.2, but using a specific branch in the git clone, which is **gcc7-fixes,** and it worked.

> cd ws/src

> git clone -b gcc7-fixes https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git

> cd ~/ws

> catkin_make

The catkin_make install was not necessary for me. My english is rusty, but I hope I've helped!

---

Originally posted by [hericles](https://answers.ros.org/users/55451/hericles/) with karma: 11 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1